# How to make two-role relationships with my auth

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and I am doing a project, but as I try to familiarize myself with this framework since I come from doing code with only php. How can I make my two column inner join of my users table?

I have a table called *a* and *b*. With only two columns, the *id* and *a_name* or *b_name*

In my users table I have two columns called *a_user* and *b_user*

and print it as is **{{auth () -> user () -> name_user}}**

***a and b are examples***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I think you'll get better answers if you can clarify your question a bit... you say you have "a table called a and b" -- do you have 2 tables, a and b?  Or one table with two columns? 
Also, it's not clear how your code example relates to your title -- I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  It's helpful if you can state what you're expecting to see vs. what you are actually seeing, and share the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, after hours, i got this solution

Model user:

```
    public function a(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\a', 'a_user'); //<====Specify column u want in the relation
    }

    public function b(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\b', 'b_user'); 
    }
```

Model a & b:

```
   //Table name
    protected $table = 'a';

    //primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
```

Print code:

```
{{auth()->user()->'a or b'->name_'a or b'}}
```